# how to get delphi Xe2 Indy 10 socket server peer host name

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

Here is my code...

```
procedure TMainForm.tsConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s, INstr, adr:string;
  port: Integer;
begin
  with TMyContext(AContext) do
  begin
    Con := Now;
    if (Connection.Socket <> nil) then
      IP :=Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
    port:=Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort;
    s:=IntToStr(Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort);
    TIdStack.IncUsage();
    try
      adr:= GStack.HostName;
    finally
      TIdStack.DecUsage;
    end;

    INstr := Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    Nick := INstr;

    if Nick <> '' then
    begin
      memo1.Lines.Add('Opened  <'+Nick + '>  '+adr+' '+IP+':'+s+'      '+DAteTimeToStr(now));
      //SendNicks;
    end else
    begin
      Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('No Nick provided! Goodbye.');
      Connection.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

GStack.HostName gives name of my server, how to get client host name?

Answer (score 3):

Use `TIdStack.HostByAddress()` to get the client's remote hostname, eg:

```
adr := GStack.HostByAddress(IP);
```

With that said, you do not need to call `TIdStack.IncUsage()` and `TIdStack.DecUsage()` because `TIdTCPServer` handles that for you in its constructor and destructor, respectively.  But more importanly, your direct access of the `TMemo` is not thread-safe.  Remember that `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  The `OnConnect` event (and `OnDisconnect` and `OnExecute` runs in a worker thread, not the main thread.  UI access must be done in the main thread instead.

Try this:

```
procedure TMainForm.tsConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  INstr, adr: string;
  port: Integer;
begin
  with TMyContext(AContext) do
  begin
    Con := Now;
    IP := Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
    port := Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort;

    adr := GStack.HostByAddress(IP);

    INstr := Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    Nick := INstr;

    if Nick <> '' then
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          memo1.Lines.Add('Opened  <' + Nick + '>  ' + adr + ' ' + IP + ':' + IntToStr(port) + '      ' + DateTimeToStr(Con));
        end
      );
      //SendNicks;
    end else
    begin
      Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('No Nick provided! Goodbye.');
      Connection.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
uses
  ..., IdSync;

type
  TMemoNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    FMsg: String;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

procedure TMemoNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  MainForm.Memo1.Lines.Add(FMsg);
end;

procedure TMainForm.tsConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  INstr, adr: string;
  port: Integer;
begin
  with TMyContext(AContext) do
  begin
    Con := Now;
    IP := Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
    port := Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort;

    adr := GStack.HostByAddress(IP);

    INstr := Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    Nick := INstr;

    if Nick <> '' then
    begin
      with TMemoNotify.Create do
      begin
        FMsg := 'Opened  <' + Nick + '>  ' + adr + ' ' + IP + ':' + IntToStr(port) + '      ' + DateTimeToStr(Con);
        Notify;
      end;
      //SendNicks;
    end else
    begin
      Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('No Nick provided! Goodbye.');
      Connection.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;
end;
```